# Selection of the appropriate random structure in a partially non counterbalanced experimental design

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design

We designed a study manipulating two factors: one factor (FACTOR1) has 2 levels (A,B), the second factor (FACTOR2) has three levels (C,D,E) . Because in psychology we often have to carry out unreasonably time-consuming experiments we planned to split the experiment (3by2) in two experiments (2by2) in which participants were exposed to all levels of FACTOR1 and only two levels of FACTOR2. One level (C - the logical reference level) of FACTOR2 was presented to all participants while the half of participans exposed to D were not exposed to E (and viceversa). We had 41 participants and 60 different item. I thought we could use mixed models to exploit the better precision in estimating C and by-item-fully crossed design, still keeping decent power to capture differences between D and E, with no need to add a third (by-subjects) factor referring to which Experiment participants were assigned to.

A dummy dataset would look like the following:

```
sj  item  FACTOR1  FACTOR2  y
1   1     A        C        123
1   2     B        C        145
1   3     A        D        110
1   4     B        D        NA
2   1     A        C        159
2   2     B        C        189
2   3     A        E        165
2   4     B        E        123
```

Since the specification of the correct random structure is crucial to gain conservative results I fitted the maximal structure and tested the interaction:

y~FACTOR1*FACTOR2+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|sj)+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|it)

the model perfectly fits, no convergence issues, and covariance matrices mostly show low correlation.

But what about the adjustments for single subjects for those levels (D and E) that participants were not exposed to, as assigned to only one of the two experiments? Should I allow for those adjustments because estimated on the basis of the by-item component of variance, or should I prefer the less maximal (and likely less conservative) specification?

y~FACTOR1*FACTOR2+(1+FACTOR1|sj)+(1+FACTOR1*FACTOR2|it)